# div disappears after setting innerHTML on onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show the options on the second dropdown from database depending on the option selected in first dropdown. I have completed my half way.I am sending xmlhttp request by onchange event in javascript. but the problem is when i select the option from the first dropdown, second div which includes second dropdown get disapperas. below is the code which i have tried:

```
<select id="field" onchange="change_field();">
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option4</option>
</select>

<div class="input-field col s2" id="branch">
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose branch</option>
    </select>
    <label>Select Branch</label>
</div>
```

**JS Onchange function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function change_field()
        {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","get_branch?field="+document.getElementById("field").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("branch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    </script>
```

Here, the perfect output which i want to see is shown in `alert();` So, how can i stop disappearing the div/second dropdown.

Comment: How does the "branch" element look like?

Comment: i have just edited my question @iuliu.net

Comment: What does this show? `alert(xmlhttp.responseText);`

Comment: alert shows:
`<select>
   <option>Output1</option>
   <option>Output2</option>
   <option>Output3</option>
</select>`

Which i exevtly want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stqm3j3g/ This is working without issue. Is it possible there is more code somewhere that is removing the outer element?

Comment: can you suggest what can be it?